# From Angular2 Validation

Tags: validation, angular

Hello I would like to know if is possible to create a if statement within the form group of Angular2.

I want if the user click on the checkbox then the input field test should be considered(the field should be required) otherwise not. How can I realise it?

**Angular2 file**

```
    constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
    this.recordform = fb.group({
        name:['',Validators.required],
        if(checkbox == true){    
        test:['',Validators.required]
        }
    });

}
```

**HTML File**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="sr-only" for="name">test</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name"  id="name" placeholder="name"  >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox"class="form-control" formControlName="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="">test</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="sr-only" for="test">test</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="test"  id="test" placeholder="test"  >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


                                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
    this.recordform = fb.group({
        name:['',Validators.required],
        test:['',Validators.required]
        }
    });
    this.recordform.controls.test.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
         if(!value) 
           this.recordform.removeControl('test');
         else 
           this.recordform.addControl('test', new FormControl('test', Validators.required));
       });
}
```

Comment: Ok but here I have not a decision via checkbox if I want to fill out the textbox or not. What is if I have more input fields after I clicked the checkbox? I need to addControl for each textfield?

Comment: You can group them and add/remove whole group... For example: `fb.group({ address: fb.group({ city: '', street: '' }), name: '' })`.

Comment: your code above is not working. declarations errors...also }} to much brackets, etc..

Comment: @Tony Should be fixed now

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.

Comment: How can I set the checkbox false as default value?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Below is that app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidator } from './custom-validators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [`./app.component.css`]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  recordForm: FormGroup;
  checkbox: FormControl;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.recordForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
      checkbox: this.fb.control(''),
      test: this.fb.control('')
    }, {
        validator: CustomValidator.checkCheckbox()
      });
    this.checkbox = this.recordForm.get('checkbox') as FormControl;
  } // End Of Init
} // End of Class
```

Put them all ass a Form Control and apply a custom validator to the Form Group's second parameter. I also created a property in the class for the checkbox control to access it in the html. Below is the app.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="recordForm">
  <label>Name: <input formControlName="name" type="text" ></label>
  <label>Checkbox: <input formControlName="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label>
  <label *ngIf="checkbox.value">Test: <input formControlName="test" type="text"></label>
</div>
```

Putting an if statement on the test control label to show only if the checkbox value is true. Below is the custom-validator.ts.

```
export class CustomValidator {
    static checkCheckbox() {
        return (control) => {
            const checkbox = control.get('checkbox');
            const test = control.get('test');
            const testValue = test.value.trim();
            return (!checkbox.value) || (checkbox.value && testValue !== '') ? null : { checkCheckbox: true };
        }; // End of return (control)=>
    } // End of method
} // End of Class
```

In this case if the checkbox value isn't checked or if it is checked and the test value isn't empty the method will return null(valid) otherwise it will return an object key that is true(invalid). Hope this helps!